# sqlite database is not changed when inserting records

Tags: ios, sqlite

In this *very simple* iPad application I'm trying to insert records into a table in the database and then retrieve them. The insert operation is completed but no change in the database and I can't see where the problem is.

Here is the project with the database.
http://www.4shared.com/zip/qTmrrpcc/ghadeer1.html

Thank you.

Comment: Get an app such as [Base 2](http://menial.co.uk/base/) and look at the data base.

Comment: Would you edit your question and post the relevant part of your code?

Comment: No one wants to see your whole project. Show us how you open the database (and from where) and show the code to insert data.

Comment: I did search before but I didn't understand the solutions because I just started programming for iOS. Thank you anyway for your comments.

Answer (score 0):

I see two `sqlite3_open` commands, one which opens the database in the `Documents` folder, another which opens it in the bundle. The former is correctly copying the database from the bundle to `Documents` before opening it from there. But clearly any inserts you do in that database won't be reflected when you subsequently open the copy in the bundle. Both `sqlite3_open` commands should follow the same process: Copy from bundle to `Documents`, if not already there, and then open the database in `Documents`.

---

Your `getschools` method also has a bug. It says:

```
- (IBAction)getschools:(id)sender {
    static NSInteger currentIndex = 0;
    if (++currentIndex == [self.schools count]) {
        currentIndex=0;
    } else {
        school *aschool = (school *) [self.schools objectAtIndex: currentIndex];
        [self.idview setText:aschool.schoolid];
        [self.nameview setText:aschool.schoolname];
    }
}
```

It should probably say:

```
- (IBAction)getschools:(id)sender {
    static NSInteger currentIndex = 0;
    if (++currentIndex == [self.schools count]) {
        currentIndex=0;
    } 

    school *aschool = (school *) [self.schools objectAtIndex: currentIndex];
    [self.idview setText:aschool.schoolid];
    [self.nameview setText:aschool.schoolname];
}
```

I only mention it because the bug could prevent you from seeing the record you just inserted, which is confusing when you're diagnosing genuine database bugs elsewhere.

Comment: It worked! thank you very much for your helpful solution. It wasn't showing the record I just inserted because retrieving the records was in the viewdidload then i moved it to the button action.